# Google App Engine + JDO + Datastore: OR operator on key based filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I'm trying to get a list of instances from Datastore through a query that filters on an unowned relation on a field named "account". This query works (it returns some results):

```
SELECT FROM it.example.model.Entity
WHERE (account == alias0)
PARAMETERS com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key alias0
ORDER BY creationDate desc RANGE 0,10
```

this query doesn't (it returns an empty resultset):

```
SELECT FROM it.example.model.Entity
WHERE (account == alias0 || account == alias1)
PARAMETERS com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key alias0, com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key alias1
ORDER BY creationDate desc RANGE 0,10
```

I cannot figure out why the OR relation does not work!

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `or`:

```
SELECT FROM it.example.model.Entity
WHERE (account == alias0 or account == alias1)
PARAMETERS com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key alias0,    
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key alias1
ORDER BY creationDate desc RANGE 0,10
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't specify that the query above is JDOSQL, so it must be "||", otherwise it throws `org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryCompilerSyntaxException` (see http://db.apache.org/jdo/jdoql.html and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries)